# Cannot write in ~/Library/Application Support after package a Qt/C++ application in MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, pkgbuild, productbuild

I'm writing my app logs in ~/Library/Application Support (QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation[0]) and all goes well if I start my app from Qt Creator. After package the app with **pkgbuild** and **productbuild**, signing the app with my Developer ID Application (for codesign) and Developer ID Installer (for productbuild), when I install it in my machine, with admin rights, log file is not generated (directory tree it is generated). I'm using std::ofstream to write into file the message that comes in QByteArray. Also, I'm using **qInstallMessageHandler**.

Any idea how make it works? Need I to add something to my **Distribution.xml** in productbuild? Any more entitlement that I need to add in packaging step?

This is a handler that I'm using

```
void tracesOutputHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext& context, const QString & msg)
{
    std::cout << "This is called" << std::endl;
    QString txt;
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        txt = QString("Debug: %1").arg(msg);
        break;
    case QtWarningMsg:
        txt = QString("Warning: %1").arg(msg);
        break;
    case QtCriticalMsg:
        txt = QString("Critical: %1").arg(msg);
        break;
    case QtFatalMsg:
        txt = QString("Fatal: %1").arg(msg);
        break;
    }

    // log_name here is well-formed.
    QFile outFile(log_name);
    if (outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)) {
        QTextStream ts(&outFile);
        ts << txt << endl;
    } else {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Cannot open in log file";
    }
}
```

This is called message appears in QtCreator execution.

Also, just add that the app is not sandboxed.

EDIT: After a lot of tests, I think that MessageHandler tracesOutputHandler is not being called when application start doing double click in app icon.

Comment: Can you post the code of your message handler? Do you create the directory tree there? Do you check for I/O errors there?

Comment: Maybe you're sandboxing your app? Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47557477/8873508

Comment: @S. Monteleone added!

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o The app is not sandboxed.

Comment: @jgd what is the value of log_name ?

Comment: @S. Monteleone /Users/jgd/Library/Application Support/MyCompany/MyApp/log